# Recursive function is altering a variable that it shouldn't be

Tags: python, recursion

Im trying to implement a bot for tic tac toe, it searches for every possible available move and does it, then search for every possible move again, until the game finishes, it then scores +1 for a won game, -1 for a lost game, 0 for a draw.

the board is a 2d array 
Example: [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

1 for player X
-1 for Player O

The bot is run by the below code

```
get_best_move(board, toMove)

def get_best_move(board, bot_id):


    # Will evaluate each base move
    # For instance if there is currently 2 moves, will return a score for each move
    moves = get_list_moves(board)

    for key, values in moves.iteritems():
        total_score = 0
        dummy_board = board
        xy = moves[key]
        x = xy[0]
        y = xy[1]

        dummy_board[x][y] = bot_id
        if(check_winner(dummy_board)):
            # Someone Won
            winner = get_winner(dummy_board)
            if(winner == bot_id):
                total_score += 1
            elif(winner == 0):
                total_score += 0
            else:
                total_score -= 1
        else:
            print board # note 1
            total_score += get_best_move_not_main(board, bot_id*-1, bot_id)
            print board # note 2
        print "Key: " + str(key) + " - move: " + str(xy) + " score: " + str(total_score) + "end"

def get_best_move_not_main(board, whosMove, bot_id):
    # Will evaluate each base move
    # For instance if there is currently 2 moves, will return a score for each move
    moves = get_list_moves(board)
    total_score = 0

    for key, values in moves.iteritems():

        dummy_board = board
        xy = moves[key]
        x = xy[0]
        y = xy[1]

        dummy_board[x][y] = whosMove

        if(check_winner(dummy_board)):
            # Someone Won
            winner = get_winner(dummy_board)
            if(winner == bot_id):
                total_score += 1
            elif(winner == 0):
                total_score += 0
            else:
                total_score -= 1
        else:
            total_score += get_best_move_not_main(board, whosMove*-1, bot_id)

    return total_score
```

The first method get_best_move, will get all the current moves we can make, and once all options have been explored will output a score for each move

My problem is that after the first iteration Example first move - 0,0 (move in the top left corner). The board is permanently altered

So for instance when i print the board(note 1) before doing the recursion in (get_best_move) it shows [[-1,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] but after the recursion (note 2). The board is altered now being a completely full board.

I'm not sure how the board array inside of my get_best_move is being altered from the separate function (get_best_move_not_main).

github link: https://github.com/konk353535/tictactoe

Thank you :)'

Thanks for all the answers, really helpful!

Comment: `dummy_board = board` doesn't make a copy of the board. Both variables refer to the same board.

Comment: to make copy use this: `dummy_board = copy.deepcopy(board)`

Comment: oh thats really bizarr, i assumed that dummy_board would create a new variable that was set to board, and that i could manipulate dummy independent of board :( how do i go about making dummy_board seperate from board? thank you

Answer (score 2):

As @Barmar pointed out, dummy_board = board doesn't make a copy of the board, it merely refers to the same one.

I think what you want is:

```
 import copy
 dummy_board=copy.deepcopy(board)
```

This is the same for any assignement; for code like:

```
a=1
b=a
```

b refers to EXACTLY THE SAME 1 as the one in a. You won't notice this for numbers, since numbers themselves cannot be changed. You can't change anything about 1, it's just 1. If you change a or b, you are getting rid of the existing value, and putting a new value in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

`dummy_board = board` makes `dummy_board` refer to **exactly the same object** as `board`: every change made via one name also gets reflected in the other.  Even a simple `copy` is not enough for a nested list: you need a **deep** copy.  I.e,

```
import copy
...
dummy_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
```